# Finding the main text on a page

Tags: html-parsing

I need a away to find the tag containing the actual relevant text of webpage. For example on a new papers website where there are adds , menus and banners etc I need to be able to parse the webpage ,assuming it is in XHTML to simlify the scenario , and return only tag containing the actual news on the page .

The way I am thinking about it is to compare the size of text in each node and pick the node with most text . Does any one have a better idea .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about identification through xhtml header content?

Comment: Not possible . The pages being parsed are existing pages like a news site I mentioned. Will not be complying with what we need or suggest .